# Sorting kernel linux linked list

Tags: c, linux, linked-list

I have a C program that is to simulate different scheduling algorithms. Process information is read from a file. Each process' information in the file is stored in the struct below:

```
struct task_struct {
  volatile long state; /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
  unsigned int flags; /* per process flags, defined below */
  int on_rq;
  int prio, static_prio, normal_prio;
  const struct sched_class *sched_class;
  struct list_head tasks;
  pid_t pid;
  int arr;
  /* simplify accounting */
  int ticks;
  int start_tick;
  int end_tick;
  int burst;
};
```

I have a "queue" structure which will hold the list of tasks/processes

```
struct rq {
  struct task_struct *curr, *idle, *stop;
  struct list_head task_root;
};
```

I somewhat understand how kernel linked lists work and have a user version of the list.h. It seems as if most interactions with the list are defined in list.h. Anyone have an idea as how to go about trying to implement a sorting algorithm (merge probably) using the functions in that file?

Comment: Do you already know how to sort a linked list?

Comment: I haven't done it in a while but I'm sure I can

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just use `list_sort` defined in `linux/list_sort.h`? The syntax is:

```
/**
 * list_sort - sort a list
 * @priv: private data, opaque to list_sort(), passed to @cmp
 * @head: the list to sort
 * @cmp: the elements comparison function
 *
 * This function implements "merge sort", which has O(nlog(n))
 * complexity.
 *
 * The comparison function @cmp must return a negative value if @a
 * should sort before @b, and a positive value if @a should sort after
 * @b. If @a and @b are equivalent, and their original relative
 * ordering is to be preserved, @cmp must return 0.
 */
void list_sort(void *priv, struct list_head *head,
        int (*cmp)(void *priv, struct list_head *a,
            struct list_head *b))
```

Comment: I was unaware of this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an undefined reference/no file exists when I include <linux/list_sort>. Doing a search I see the file exists at: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/list_sort.h. Is there something else I need to do @Subhasis?

Comment: when I include <linux/list_sort.h>*

Comment: Try passing -I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include to the compiler flags.

Comment: What is the priv parameter? I can't find any other documentation on it.